# Bug with Php Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a PHP page which displays n number of records in form of table from database(till here pagination works fine). Using a search field i am triggering another query, which displays the results in 2 pages. The first page shows the result fine, but when i click on the 2nd page link, it displays the result from the initial query.

any suggestions would help me to identify the actual issue that is causing this.

Thanks!

Comment: You should share your code with question.

Answer (score 0):

As a was stuck with same issue earlier.
The solution is to pass searching input value along pagination parameters.
In your case pagination just take it's parameter and performs its working by excluding searching query.
So just passing searching input value(Query) you will get proper result.

Comment: Instead of passing the query too, it still loads the same result set.